# What is koa:sess.sig?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, koa

I am using Passport.js with Koa, and I noticed that when a session cookie is generated, it is called `koa:sess` and contains the session information encoded as Base64. However, there is another cookie called `koa:sess.sig`, and its purpose is not obvious. My guess would be that it is intended to stop an attacker from spoofing the session (since the `koa:sess` cookie just contains the user ID), is this the case?

Comment: I had a similar question and found this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859103/how-can-i-access-cookie-session-from-client-side

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/Secbone/koa-session2):

> signed: a boolean indicating whether the cookie is to be signed (false
> by default). If this is true, another cookie of the same name with the
> .sig suffix appended will also be sent, with a 27-byte url-safe base64
> SHA1 value representing the hash of cookie-name=cookie-value against
> the first Keygrip key. This signature key is used to detect tampering
> the next time a cookie is received.